Не понимаю применение оператора?
function every(array, predicate) {
    for (let element of array) {
        if (!predicate(element))  return false;
    } return true;
}
console.log(every([1, 3, 5], n => n < 10));
console.log(every([2, 4, 16], n => n < 10));
console.log(every([], n => n < 10));

Не могу понять, если убрать оператор ! перед predicate, то средний вывод в консоль все равно будет false. Подскажите почему?

потому что условие выполняется не для всех элементов.

Потому что не все элементы меньше 10 и не все элементы больше или равны 10.

Потому что Законы де Моргана.
Исходный код:



код
описание




for (let element of array)
в массиве


return false
не


if (...(element))
существует элемент,


!predicate(element)
который не соответствует условию



твой вариант



код
описание




for (let element of array)
в массиве


return false
не


if (...(element))
существует элемент,


predicate(element)
который соответствует условию



что, очевидно, не является противоположным условием.

Потому что это будет тоже самое, что, не меняя код функции, поменять условие предиката на противоположное.
Т.е. вместо:
console.log(every([2, 4, 16], n => n < 10));

Будет:
console.log(every([2, 4, 16], n => n >= 10));

Оба условия n < 10 и n >= 10 верны не для всех элементов массива, отсюда и false.
